# C_FindObjectsInit(..) from PKCS11 class exception

Tags: java, pkcs#11

To sign data, I am using signserver open-source code. I was exploring a legacy code where
it gives error at this place:

```
Module.getPKCS11Module().C_FindObjectsInit(session.getSessionHandle(), attributes,true);
```

where the `Module` class is from `iaikpkcs11Wrapper.jar (package: iaik.pkcs.pkcs11)`
As I navigate further, `PKCS11` interface has this method `void C_FindObjectsInit(long var1, CK_ATTRIBUTE[] var3, boolean var4)`  mentioned above.

Moreover, the `attributes` param is constructed like below:

```
        CK_ATTRIBUTE[] attributes = new CK_ATTRIBUTEKeyStoreContainerBase[2];

        attributes[0] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE();
        attributes[0].type = PKCS11Constants.CKA_CLASS;
        attributes[0].pValue = new Long(PKCS11Constants.CKO_SECRET_KEY);
                
        
        attributes[1] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE();
        attributes[1].type = PKCS11Constants.CKA_ID;
        attributes[1].pValue = id; //id is byteArray. For this param's value the error is causing
```

My question is, do I need to store any kind of key/certificate from where `C_FindObjectsInit(..)` will read or match as it says that it couldn't find any key? Where does this method search the key or how to resolve this issue?
Btw, I have read [C_FindObjectsInit-JavaDoc](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs11/wrapper/PKCS11.html#C_FindObjectsInit-long-iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.CK_ATTRIBUTE:A-boolean-) and couldn't understand this line properly, that's why I am here:

> pTemplate - the object's attribute values to match and the number of
> attributes in search template (PKCS#11 param: CK_ATTRIBUTE_PTR
> pTemplate, CK_ULONG ulCount)

[this may sound peculiar question, but I am really blank and stuck for few days]

Answer (score 0):

PKCS#11 specification don't force us to use some strictly composed data.
But in most implementations I saw it was binary encoded OID field.
Also check for 0 (null) bytes in sequence.